# Can I use Entity Framework Core with ASP.NET MVC (not core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'd like to use some features from EF Core (mapping to fields) but in my ASP.NET MVC application. Is this possible? When I am trying to add migration I get:
"No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext." In usual EF the Db is just created locally in App_Data...

Does this mean the whole idea is stupid and I should use ASP.NET MVC Core?

Comment: Why do you need EF Core in the first place?

Comment: Using constructors with parameters and support of mapping to fields, not just properties,

Comment: If you have got it compiling I'd say the answer to this question is: Yes. And then the next step is how EF Core is initialized, that is indeed a litle different. No App_Data in Core...  But we see no code so there will not be many answers.